# Add data to the database using codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, content-management-system, addition

I am currently trying to add data to the database using codeigniter. I have already set up a registration page using the active method and attempted to use the same method for the add news form but was unsuccessful.

When I click submit it is saying page cannot be found and the url shows the controller function name. This is the same when i purposely leave any fields blank. I have checked my database and no records have been added and no php log errors.

Here is my snippets of code:

View:

```
<?php echo form_open('add/add_article'); ?>
        <?php echo form_input('title', set_value('title', 'Title')); ?><br />
        <?php echo form_textarea('content', set_value('content', 'Content')); ?><br />
        <?php echo form_input('author', set_value('author', 'Author')); ?>
        <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Add Article'); ?>
        <?php echo validation_errors('<p class="error">' );?>
  <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Controller:

```
class Add extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('admin/add');
}

    public function add_article() {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('content', 'Content', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('author', 'Author', 'trim|required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        $this->index();

        }else{

            $this->load->model('news_model');
            if($query = $this->news_model->addArticle()) {
            $this->load->view('news');
            }else {
                $this->load->view('news');
        }
    }   
}
}
```

Model:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

        function addArticle() {
    $data =array(
    'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
    'content' => $this->input->post('content'), 
    'author' => $this->input->post('author'),
    'username' => $this->input->post('username'));

    $insert = $this->db->insert('news', $data);
    return $insert;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you see in your form's action in source ?

Comment: in the source i know the action is aiming towards the  add controller and add_article function and when its submitted it just shows: localhost/codeigniter/add/add_controller and then page not found, is that what you mean? Ive also tried using redirect in the controller in the if statement.

Comment: Try `echo form_open('index.php/add/add_article');`

Comment: ---Ive added my working code below my first post if you want to look at it.---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's the server that's throwing the page not found it's almost certainly a URL issue as opposed to a CI/PHP issue.

Is your base url defined properly in the config file?  Is your `.htaccess` configured properly (an old configuration could be routing /add requests away from CI)?

Try adding the following action to the Add controller, and navigating to it directly at `http://[base]/add/thetest`

```
public function thetest() {
echo 'Controller accessed';
die;
}
```

If it still says *page not found* it's not your code, it's your config (either server config or CI).

Comment: I tried this and when testing it still threw a CI page url not found i added admin to the add/the test and the echo was found, so now i have added the "admin" to the form open, if query in my controller. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of insert use update in your model like:

```
$insert = $this->db->update('news', $data);
return $insert;
```

And I think that this part of your code in controller is wrong too (wrong if statement and no data send to model):

```
if($query = $this->news_model->addArticle()) {
            $this->load->view('news');
            }else {
                $this->load->view('news');
        }
```

try this:

```
$data =array(
    'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
    'content' => $this->input->post('content'), 
    'author' => $this->input->post('author'),
    'username' => $this->input->post('username')
);

$query = $this->news_model->addArticle($data);
if($query) 
{
   // query ok
   $this->load->view('news');
}
else {
   // no query
   $this->load->view('news');
}
```

Comment: I have saved this snippet for future reference but when using the $insert = $this->db->update('news', $data); this updated all my records in the database rather than add a new row.